# Iterating over elements in column add new value - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When iterating through column elements (Y,Y,nan,Y in my case) for some reason I can't add a new element when a condition is met (if twice Y,Y is encountered) I want to replace the last Y with: "encountered" or simply just add it or rewrite it since I have track of the index number.

I have a dataframe

```
    col0       col1
1    A          Y
2    B          Y
3    B          nan
4    C          Y
```

code:

```
count = 0
for i,e in enumerate(df[col1]):    
    if 'Y' in e:
        count += 1 
    else:
         count = 0
    if count == 2:
      df['col1'][i] = 'encountered' #Index errror: list index out of range
```

error message:
IndexError: list index out of range

Even if I try to specify the index in which column-cell I would like to 'add the msg to' gives me the same error:
code;

df['col1'][1] = 'or this'

**main idea direct example:**
df['col1'][2] = 'under index 2 in column1 add this msg'

is it because of the pyPDF2/utils is interfering?

*warning:*

```
  File "C:\Users\path\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\utils.py", line 69, in formatWarning
    file = filename.replace("/", "\\").rsplit("\\", 1)[1] # find the file name
```

*error:*
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
last_index=df[df['col1']=='Y'].index[-1]
df.loc[last_index,'col1']='encountered'
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. Can you provide me a bit of an explanation why the aforementioned approach of mine didn't work (even though it did before?!)

Comment: I could not able to recreate the error. i'm getting different error. TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would go about solving this:

```
prev_val = None

# Iterate through rows to utilize the index
for idx, row in df[['col1']].iterrows():

    # unpack your row, a bit more overhead but highly readable
    val = row['col1']

    # Use previous value instead of counter – is easier to read and is more accurate
    if val == 'Y' and val == prev_val:
        df.loc[idx, 'col1'] = 'encountered'

    # now set the prev value to current:
    prev_val = val
```

Answer (score 0):

What possibly could be the issue with your code is the way you are iterating over your dataframe and also the indexing. Another issue is that you are trying to set the value you are iterating over with a new value. That bound give you issues later.

Does this works for you?:

```
>>> count = 0
>>> df['encounter'] = np.nan

>>> for i in df.itertuples():
>>>     if getattr(i, 'col1')=='Y':
>>>         count+=1
>>>     else:
>>>         count = 0
     
>>>     if count==2:
>>>         df.loc[i[0], 'encounter']= 'encountered'

>>> print(df)

  col0 col1    encounter
0    A    Y          NaN
1    B    Y  encountered
2    B  NaN          NaN
3    C    Y          NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! df.loc[last_index,'col1']='encountered' did the trick. I'm still not sure why my approach wasn't working. The whole background is a bit different, i just simplified the problem. But yes definitely had to do something with way i was locating the column/row